# Debug Unhandled Promise Rejections

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, knex.js

I have written to following db query to get back all posts with a certain offset:

```
async function getPaginationPosts(start, size) {
    try {
        const posts = await knex("posts").select().where({
            deleted: false,
        }).orderBy("createdAt").limit(size).offset(start)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        console.log(e.stack)
    }
    return posts
}
```

However, I am getting the following `Unhandled Promise Rejection`

```
(node:1824) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: posts is n
ot defined
(node:1824) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejection
s that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My problem is that I do not get any further information about the error in the console.

Any suggestions from your site:

1. How to debug these types of rejections properly?
2. What is wrong with the above code?

Thank you in advance for your replies!

**Update**

I changed my function to the following:

```
async function getPaginationPosts(size, offset) {
    try {
        return await knex("posts").select().where({
            deleted: false,
        }).orderBy("createdAt").limit(size).offset(offset)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        console.log(e.stack)
        return null
    }
}
```

Now I am getting the following exception:

```
(node:9096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: start is n
ot defined
```

I do not use a variable `start` in my function.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`posts` are defined not in the correct place. Define them outside of `try/catch` block or return result from `try` block:

```
async function getPaginationPosts(start, size) {
    try {
        return await knex("posts").select().where({
            deleted: false,
        }).orderBy("createdAt").limit(size).offset(start)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        console.log(e.stack)
        return null
    }
}
```

Or:

```
async function getPaginationPosts(start, size) {
    let posts
    try {
        posts = await knex("posts").select().where({
            deleted: false,
        }).orderBy("createdAt").limit(size).offset(start)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        console.log(e.stack)
    }
    return posts
}
```

Comment: Thank you or your reply alexmac. I adapted my function. However, still I get a PromiseRejection. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here and how to debug these types of rejections properly? Thx in advance!

Comment: Looks like that the second error is not related to `getPaginationPosts` function. What other functions do you call together with `getPaginationPosts`? Also, be sure that all code of functions marked as `async` is in `try/catch` blocks. Check each async function.

Answer (score 16):

A convenient way to log unhandled rejections - is to add listener (usually at entry point of your app, i.e. main.js) that looks like this

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", (error) => {
  console.error(error); // This prints error with stack included (as for normal errors)
  throw error; // Following best practices re-throw error and let the process exit with error code
});
```

Comment: I hate node >:-((((

Comment: This really helps if you work with a big application.